# Need help identifying a sci-fi short story (shocked from a band saw, comes to in a slightly altered timeline)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, soft-sci-fi

I recall reading this fantastic sci-fi short story in a book of collected short stories, I just can't remember the name or author.

I read it maybe between 2010 and 2015, it was in a thick book of collected sci-fi stories with a title like "xxth edition of the {world's?} best sci-fi short stories". I don't know when the story itself was originally published, but my guess is that it was sometime between 1970 - 2010?

Briefly, some guy is shocked from using a band saw, and when he comes to he finds himself in a slightly altered timeline where key events have changed in minor ways. There's some classic back-and-forth between him and his family about his recollection / perception of events.

The story closes with him realizing that his wife (who had died in the original timeline) was alive in this one.

Can any of the experts here help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I read it maybe between 2010 and 2015, it was in a thick book of collected sci-fi stories with a title like "xxth edition of the {world's?} best sci-fi short stories". I don't know when the story itself was originally published, but my guess is that it was sometime between 1970 - 2010?

Comment: Found it! (didn't realize Google could narrow my search to "Books" only)

The story was "Calling Your Name" by Howard Waldrop and it was in The Year's Best Science Fiction, the Twenty-First Annual Collection (edited by Gardner Dozois)

If you're not familiar with it, I highly recommend.

Thanks to everyone for your willingness to help!

Comment: Please do post your own answer identifying the correct story. We'd also be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the answer in your previous comment. As I said, you can post that as an actual answer if you like, and hopefully earn some reputation from it. If you don't wish to post an actual answer yourself, another user will probably step in and do it after a grace period. If that happens, we'd still appreciate it if you'd mark the answer as accepted, and since it wouldn't be a self-answer in that scenario, you could do so as soon as the answer is posted.

Comment: I rolled back your question to revision 2, as we don't like answers to be edited into the questions themselves. Instead, they should be posted via the 'Your Answer' field below. If you're happy to do that, please be my guest. You can copy and paste the text from your previous edit if you like.